# Java Multithread

Tags: java

Can One JVM handle multiple JVM ? As One JVM handles Multiple Threads, So I mean to ask That can one JVM handle multiple JVM treating them as thread? If Possible Please share with me the soln and example as well

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want multiple JVM for ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) to launch external processes, which could easily be a Java execution.  Then you'd have a handle to the process running in another JVM, and you could interact with it (by sending it "console" input and reading its output) from a thread.

However, in this case the second JVM wouldn't be running *inside* the first, but merely *alongside* it with the two able to communicate via streams.  Depending on what you're looking for this may or may not suffice.

Perhaps if you gave an example of whatyou're trying to achieve?  I can't think of any reason you'd actually need nested JVMs, so I don't think you're asking your **real** question.

Edit: What you are trying to do sounds like a recipe for disaster.  If you want to speed up your application, use a profiler such as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), identify the areas where your application spends a lot of its time, and look at ways to define those areas more efficiently.

If you write *good, clean* code the JVM (in conjunction with the underlying OS) will execute it efficiently for you.

Your question implies a misunderstanding of the general principles of how to improve a program's performance; it's like using a screwdriver with the wrong size head, then going off to get a pneumatic drill because the screw won't go in.  It will not work, and it will end in disaster.

(Does anyone know of a good "first steps in performance tuning Java" tutorial that could be linked here?  Thanks.)

Comment: Running more JVMs on the same machine won't help performance.

Comment: Shall I re-frame my Question?

Comment: Basically I am trying to achieve Hyper Threading Technology in Java

Comment: It would be great if i can get help from all of You

Comment: @Sujeet - **What**?  I honestly have no idea what would have convinced you that that's something you need/want to do.  Hyperthreading is done *within the CPU*, and the operating system will schedule OS threads for you.  Your role as a Java programmer, is to define the classes and logic that efficiently performs the task you need.  It's up to the JVM, the OS and the hardware to actually run that quickly.  If you *really* need to do hyperthreading, you should be writing device drivers in C.  (But thankfully you don't).